# Need help on arithmetic mean query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system that Works like this:

Users from many company sectors vote in many other companies.

Example: John from a car company 1 votes Supermarket company, Shopping center, etc.

There are more than 1 company for each sector. I mean, there is car company 1, car company 2, etc.

John from car company 2 CAN NOT vote on its competitor - Car company 2. Car Company 2 won't even appear on the vote page.

However, I got a problem. When showing the results on the admin page, It's counting all votes. So, for Car Company 2, it will count all votes (including John's), but John's note will be 0.

I don't want It to count, do you know what I mean?

Example: Car Company 2 got these results: 10, 8, 4, 9 and 0 (John's vote) So the math will be (10 + 8 + 4 + 9 + 0)/5, when It should be (10 + 8 + 4 + 9)/4. Remember: there isn't always going to have competitors companies in each sector 
Here's  my query.

```
SELECT sum(vt.nota) totalvoto, (sum(vt.nota) * 10/pc.pessoas_votos)/10 media, pc.id, pc.pessoas_votos, pc.nome_peca, vt.nota, vt.data, vt.hora, pc.id_subcategoria, emp.nome_empresa FROM pecas pc, votos vt, empresas emp where pc.id = vt.id_peca 
and vt.id_categoria = 2 
and pc.empresa = emp.id
```

I tried many things but I can't get it to work. Would making the DEFAULT value for the notes NULL and searching for values that are different from NULL on the query? 
Sorry for my bad english - It's not my main language plus I'm in a hurry. Thank you all!

Edit:
The votes are stored in the "votes" table. Table structure:

```
id, usuario, id_peca, nota, data, hora
```

Where ID is the auto-increment value, usuario is who voted, id_peca is in which company he voted, nota is the note he gave to the company and data and hora are the date plus time.

When company "x" receives notes 8, 4, 0(because one of the voters was it's directly competitor) it gets a media of 4 (8+4+0/3), when It should receive (8+4/2). Changing the default value of the column on the DB will solve it, right? I mean, changing the default value to  "DEFAULT" and on the query make it search for everything except when the note value is "DEFAULT".

Comment: Don't apologize for your English, you write better than most Americans. I would however try to add some sample tables and data and expected results to better demonstrate your question and goal.

Comment: Sure. As soon as I get home I'll post it. Thank you for the answer!!

Comment: "Do you know what I mean?" Um, no. Can you explain in Portuguese? And why's everybody called John?

Comment: Rather than 'DEFAULT' you can use a NULL value to indicate a vote that not be counted. (This will be easier than writing a condition to leave out employees from the same sector, who should not be allowed to vote; you could do that too by JOINing the table against itself.)Also note that mysql has a built-in aggregate function called 'AVG' so you don't need to SUM and divide.

Comment: Often JOINs mess up aggregations.  See if you can get the desired rows only once, perhaps by changing the other two tables in to a subquery.